# How to dynamically change static limit php?

Tags: php

I set a start date and end date to show a content.

`$sdate = 2015-07-20 0:0`

`$edate = 2015-07-30 0:0`

Now in php how to set this?

**php**

```
static $module = 0;
if($module < 1) {   
$this->data['module'] = $module++;
}
```

**tpl**

```
<?php echo $module; ?>
```

output is `0` . Now i want if i set `start date` and `end date` and when output `0` ended then auto define next module number `1`

Comment: Is this within a class?

Answer (score 1):

Your static attribute should ideally be in a class:

```
class MyClass {

    public static $module = 0;

}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
if (MyClass::$module < 1) 
{
    $this->data['module'] = MyClass::$module++;
}
```

Further reading for you here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I think it is within a class @diggersworld

Comment: Time to start reading the manual then, check out the link at the end of my answer, there's a section on static variables, starts at Example #4.

Comment: can you do this without class? @diggersworld